# Is there a word or music term for when a singer is mimicing the instrument, like at the beginning of the song Dang Me by Roger Miller?

Tags: technique, voice, terminology, instruments

Title is self-explanatory.  I'm asking if there is a word or musical term for when a singer is mimicking the sound of the instrument that's playing.  An example of what I'm asking for is at the very beginning of the song Dang Me by Roger Miller.

Comment: You might check out the Mills Brothers too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mills_Brothers

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple form of [scat singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing). The term is mostly used in jazz, but in the Roger Miller example it's used in much the same way: a bluesy-improvised lick that mimics an instrument.

Comment: And sort of related is beat boxing where lots of percussion sounds are mimicked.

Comment: This is indeed example of scat singing, but to me it doesn't aim to mimic sound of any specific instrument. Scat singing doesn't need to mimic any specific instrument.